# How can I allow linebreaks after backslash `\` characters?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, linebreak

I have an answer which involves a very long filepath.

> 1. Search for regedit, and then press Enter.
> 2. Open **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace**

I'd like to allow linebreaks after the backslash `\` characters to prevent folder names from being cut-off between lines.

I have tried inserting break characters, ([U+0082, Break Permitted Here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0082/index.htm)), but they are being displayed as commas `,` in the markdown preview.

I would like to avoid manually adding a single newline with two spaces  if possible. It's a hacky solution which doesn't work well with variable font and screen sizes, and means the newline would be included when copy-pasting the file path.

**How can I tell my text to break after `\` characters?**

Answer (score 6):

Don't do it. It's more important to display text that can be copied and pasted.

If you include an invisible space, that space *will* be included in copied text by all major browsers. (You claim the contrary, but I tested by copying from [animuson's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299847) in Firefox 54 and Chrome 60 under both Linux and Windows as well as IE 9 under Windows, all of them copied the U+8203 character.) Since this is an invisible character, people won't notice and will run into all kinds of strange errors.

Modern CSS does allow having displayed text that's different from copied text, and Stack Exchange's formatting engine makes use of it. It inserts a line break before the backslash rather than after, and it would break at a space if there was one, but that's not too bad. When you copy, in a modern browser, you get the intended text, with no line breaks or other spurious characters.

Since this is code, you should use code formatting, not bold.

> 1. Search for `regedit`, and then press Enter.
> 2. Open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`.

```
1. Search for `regedit`, and then press Enter.
2. Open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`.
```

If you don't want a line break at all, you can use displayed code.

> 1. Search for `regedit`, and then press Enter.
> 2. Open
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace
>    ```

```
1. Search for `regedit`, and then press Enter.
2. Open

        HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace
```

Answer (score 4):

The more common character used in HTML is the zero-width space: `&#8203;`

It essentially puts a space between two characters that doesn't have any width to it. So if the word is too long, the browser sees that space and allows the word to break at that point. If it fits, though, it won't affect how it runs together (since it has no width).

> 1. Search for regedit, and then press Enter.
> 2. Open **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\​Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace**

You should always be careful using invisible characters, though. Copying and pasting them into other programs can cause weird things to happen.

Comment: It's worth noting that Google Chrome auto-removes invisible characters when copy-pasting text, so that shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: assuming they use a chrome style browser. Its probably a better idea to have the actual code you want and overrun a line, than have some mangled mess with zero width spaces that's pretty looking but not functional